# MPI get the number of non-finalized processes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have the following code

```
int main(void) {
   ...
   int numtasks, rank;
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   int k = 2;
   if (rank == 3) {
       do {
          ...
       } while (number_of_not_finalized_processes >= numtasks - k);
   }
   ...
   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

and want to loop process with `rank = 3` until `k` processes are finalized with `MPI_Finalize()`. How can I find out, how many processes have been finalized and define `number_of_not_finalized_processes` ? Or maybe I have any better alternative way to find out how many processes are still alive or passed the certain part of code?

Comment: Two solutions given in an answer. But are you sure you need such heavy machinery? What's the context for the question?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I want to make a program with N users and M servers. Each user wants to make unknown number of read/write operations on the servers. And I need somehow to understand when the requests are over from users to servers.

I can use special MPI_Send at the very end of each of my user processes to notify servers that interaction with ith user is over. But I think, there may be some better, more appropriate way to indicate the end of such session.

Comment: A special message is not a bad solution. You need a notification of some sort anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with one-sided communication. Create a window where every process before it finalizes:

1. Acquires a lock on the window on rank 3
2. Uses `MPI_Accumulate` to increase the counter

This is a very asynchronous solution. If your processes do something synchronized, say a loop where they dynamically decide to exit the loop, you could for instance at the synchonization point create a subcommunicator of only the active processes.